# Определнное количество ngFor

Tags: angular4

Вопрос в том как в ngFor проитерировать только определенное количество объектов. Например если есть масив из 10 объеков как проитерировать только первые три. Для всех используеться *ngFor ="let idex of masiv"

Comment: например `masiv.slice(0,3)`

Comment: Но это нужно делать в компоненте. Хотелось бы узнать можно ли это как то организовать именно в шаблоне.

Comment: Это можно и в шаблоне делать

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Тоесть как то так? <div *ngFor="let index of masiv.slice(0,3)">

Comment: спасибо именно так это и работает)